# How to merge 2 array of Objects?

Tags: javascript

I have the following codes for 2 array of objects the way I like it should get merge is:

```js
let arrofObj1 = [
  {
    apple: 17,
    mango: 15,
  },
  {
    apple: 20,
    mango: 29,
  },
];

let arrofObj2 = [
  {
    banana: 60,
    pear: 19,
  },
  {
    banana: 50,
    pear: 39,
  },
];

let outPutIwant = [
  {
    apple: 17,
    mango: 15,
    banana: 60,
    pear: 19,
  },
  {
    apple: 20,
    mango: 29,
    banana: 50,
    pear: 39,
  },
];
```

Note: There could be more than 2 objects from each array before adding but this is how I want them to add. Can anyone tell me how can I do this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can improve your question showing the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each item in `arrofObj1` and get the object at the same index in `arrofObj2`, then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all enumerable properties over.

```js
let arrofObj1 = [{
    apple: 17,
    mango: 15
  },
  {
    apple: 20,
    mango: 29
  }
]

let arrofObj2 = [{
    banana: 60,
    pear: 19
  },
  {
    banana: 50,
    pear: 39
  }
]


arrofObj1.forEach((e, i)=>Object.assign(e, arrofObj2[i]))
console.log(arrofObj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this. Note that this function assumes that your two arrays contain the same number of objects each.

```js
var arrofObj1 = [
  {
    apple: 17,
    mango: 15,
  },
  {
    apple: 20,
    mango: 29,
  },
];

var arrofObj2 = [
  {
    banana: 60,
    pear: 19,
  },
  {
    banana: 50,
    pear: 39,
  },
];


function mergeByPosition(arr1, arr2) {
    let arrResult = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        const objResult = { ...arr1[i], ...arr2[i] };
        arrResult.push(objResult);
    }
    return arrResult;
}

console.log(mergeByPosition(arrofObj1, arrofObj2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.map((item, index) => {
    return { ...item, ...arr2[index] };
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty easy map and merge problem.

```
const result = arrofObj1.map((obj, index) => ({
  ...obj,
  ...arrofObj2[index]
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const outPutIwant =
  arrofObj1.map((a, i) =>
    Object.assign({}, a, arrofObj2[i])
  );
```

This loops over `arrofObj1` (using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), and for each such item `a`, uses [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to make a copy of its contents and also assign the corresponding item `i` from `arrofObj2`.